# (RBAC) Role Based Access Control on Individual Feature Gates Or Rules in Statsig

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, .net-core, statsig

Is it Possible to have Role based Edit/Delete access on individual Feature Gates Or Rules in Statsig?

Example:-

Suppose I want to implement that "user-1" **should not be** able to Edit/Delete "Feature-Gate-1" or "Rule-1" in "Feature-Gate-1", but **should be** able to edit/delete other Feature Gates or Rules in the same Project.

Please let me know, if this is possible in statsig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statsig has entity level reviews that you can turn on so not everyone can arbitrarily ship new things. You can read more here: https://docs.statsig.com/guides/setting-up-reviews#enforcing-team-reviews

Statsig does not support it at the rulesets level. Thinking about it a bit, that would be tricky because any ruleset ahead of the locked one could override or render the locked one useless.

Comment: I was going through this feature, and I did not get the option for "Allow Project Admins to self-approve reviews " under "Config Review Requirements".

Can you help me with this option?

Comment: This feature is available only on Pro & Enterprise tiers.  At this point you might need to ask Statsig support team.  Their slack is available at https://statsig.com/slack.